# Проблемы с EventSource

Tags: javascript, php, веб-сервер, fetch

Пытаюсь на практике понять как работает приблуда EventSource.
Вот простенький код на js:

```
let eventSource = new EventSource('/dist/EventSource.php');
eventSource.onmessage = e => {
    console.log(e.data); // хочу видеть сообщение в консоли
}
```

А вот что имеем в EventSource.php (запускаю на локальном сервере MAMP):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
echo 'data: message' . "\n\n";
?>
```

Но почему то сообщения message в консоль поступают один за другим бесконечно, хотя команду echo в php я написал один только раз.

Как сделать чтобы из php кода сообщение отправлялось только один раз? без разрыва соединения

Comment: Выполнение php-скрипта завершается — соединение разрывается, всё логично. Хотите не разрывать — делайте так, чтобы php-скрипт не завершался никогда

Answer (score 0):

EventSource как и WebSocket, держит соединение постоянно.
Используйте метод close, который завершит соединение:

```
let eventSource = new EventSource('/dist/EventSource.php');
eventSource.onmessage = e => {
    console.log(e.data); // хочу видеть сообщение в консоли
}

eventSource.close();
```